# HTTP/1.1 response code header on HTTP/2 H2 enabled server

Tags: php, apache, http, http-headers, h2

I maintain a PHP web application which sends HTTP response codes like

```
header( 'HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found' );
```

for example if an entry is not found in the database. For my question with emphasis on the prefix `HTTP/1.1`!

Now I think about enabling H2 / HTTP/2 for the Apache httpd 2.4.37 which serves the site.

Do I have to touch the PHP scripts to make the application work correctly with H2?

Or doesn't it matter? Can HTTP/1.1 responses be "tunneled" through the binary H2 connection?

Would you replace the line above with

```
header( $_SERVER[ 'SERVER_PROTOCOL' ] . ' 404 Not Found' );
```

? Will that be enough?

Comment: You might want to consider using [`http_response_code()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php)

Comment: You don't have to change PHP scripts. Just continue to return `HTTP/1.1 404`.